# What function do I need in Wordpress to resolve the URL of the child categories of a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I looked around and noticed many questions about this were asked already. But none had an answer I needed.

Below you find an php/html script of a page template in my own theme (I use them because of more functionality on corporate websites). That's NOT the problem. Works like a charm.

What does this script do?

It outputs all categories their featured image (via plugin 'Categories Images') under the taxonomy clients.

Works perfect!! That's not the problem.

The only LINE of code I need is mentioned in the PHP loop as a comment...
Could anyone please help me?

```
        <ul>
 <?php $args = array( 
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => '',
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'clients',
    'pad_counts'               => false ); ?>

<?php foreach (get_categoris($args) as $cat) : ?>
<li>
<a href=" <?php // WHAT GOES HERE?? ?>">
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>"/></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!!!
WORKS!!

```
        <ul>
 <?php $args = array( 
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 => '',
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'clients',
    'pad_counts'               => false );

 $tax_menu_items = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($tax_menu_items as $cat) : ?>
 <li>
 <a href=" <?php echo get_term_link($cat,$cat->taxonomy); ?> ">
    <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>"/>
 </a>
 </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```